# Pass arguments to a function from each row of a matrix

Tags: r

I created this function:

```
nDone<- function (under,strike,ttoe,vol,rf,dy) {
    return(pnorm(((log(under/strike) + (rf-dy+(vol^2)/2)*ttoe)/(vol*(ttoe^0.5)))))
 }

nDone(90,100,3,0.17,0.05,0)
[1] 0.6174643
```

So far that's fine and works.  Now I want the function to be applied to each row of a matrix.

```
b<- c(90,95,100,100,3,2,0.17,0.18,0.05,0.05,0,0)
dim(b) <- c(2,6)
```

Which gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   90  100    3 0.17 0.05    0
[2,]   95  100    2 0.18 0.05    0
```

So now I want to pass the elements in each row to the function. I've tried using apply:

```
apply(b,1,nDone)
```

And get the following error:

```
Error in under/strike : 'strike' is missing
```

I've also tried:

```
lapply(b,nDone)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in under/strike : 'strike' is missing
```

What I want is multiple results of the function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Um....this is exactly the same as your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235781/passing-arguments-to-a-function-in-a-single-vector) question.

Comment: Hi Joran,  I know it looks the same and I'm certainly not trying to waste anyone's time. In this question now I'm trying to pass each row of a matrix to a function. Again thanks for reviewing.

Comment: Yes.  @joran's answer (actually a comment) to the previous question should work to answer this one as well.  He left a little bit of room for struggle/interpretation on your part.  I would suggest that you take a look at his comment, see if you can understand what to do with it, then (if you can't) come back and ask for clarification there ...

Comment: Another route you could go down would be something like this: `nDone(b[,1],b[,2],b[,3],b[,4],b[,5],b[,6])`, since `nDone` is already vectorized. Or convert the matrix to a list with each column being an element and use the solution from the previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
apply(b, 1, function(x)do.call(nDone, as.list(x)))
```

What was wrong with your version is that through apply(), your nDone() function was getting the whole row as a single argument, i.e., a vector passed under "strike" and nothing for the other arguments. The solution is to use do.call().

Answer (score 3):

It is worth mentioning that, if you wanted to bind the results of the functions to the original matrix, you could use `mdply` from `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> mdply(b, nDone)

  X1  X2 X3   X4   X5 X6        V1
1 90 100  3 0.17 0.05  0 0.6174643
2 95 100  2 0.18 0.05  0 0.6249916
```