# Calculating R function with arguments which are columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following code.

```
completemodel <- function(model, colnum)
{
  modlst = c()
  tuplenum = length(model)
  if(tuplenum != 0)
    for(i in 1:tuplenum)
      modlst = c(modlst, model[[i]])
  index = seq(0, colnum-1)
  inddiff = setdiff(index, modlst)
  inddifflen = length(inddiff)
  for(i in seq(length.out=inddifflen))
    model = append(model, inddiff[i])
  return(model)
}

##   Calculate number of parameters in model.
numparam <- function(mod, colnum)
  {
    library(RJSONIO)
    mod = fromJSON(mod)
    mod = completemodel(mod, colnum)
    totnum = 0
    for(tup in mod)
      totnum = totnum +(4**length(tup))
    return(totnum)
  }

x = cbind.data.frame(rownum=c(100, 100), colnum=c(10, 20), modeltrue=c("[]", "[]"), modelresult=c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> x
  rows colnum modeltrue modelresult
1  100     10        []     [[1,2]]
2  100     20        []     [[1,3]]
```

How can I operate on `x` to give me a data frame that looks like the following? Here of course
I mean that the value of e.g. `numparam("[]", 10)` when I write `numparam("[]", 10)`.

```
  rownum   colnum    numparam_modeltrue   numparam_modelresult
  100        10      numparam("[]", 10)   numparam("[[1,2]]", 10)
  100        20      numparam("[]", 20)   numparam("[[1,3]]", 20)
```

Some version of the apply function might work, but I am having problems finding the proper formulation.

UPDATE: It seems that if the `rownnum`, `colnum` tuple is not unique, then one can do the following.

```
x = cbind.data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3), rownum=c(100, 100, 100), colnum=c(10, 20, 20), modeltrue=c("[]", "[]", "[]"),
  modelresult=c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]","[[1,3, 4]]"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

##Then, create a data.table and set the key

library(data.table)
xDT <- as.data.table(x)
setkeyv(xDT, c("id", "rownum", "colnum")
```

Is that the correct method?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: I'd be happy to, but what kind of context do you need? The code given above is complete, I think. I just want to operate on the given data frame with the `numparam` function to obtain another data frame in the manner speciried. What is unclear? This is the actual code I am using. I suppose I could come up with a simpler example to illustrate, though this one is not very complex.

Comment: `numparam_modeltrue` and `numparam_modelresult` are factors?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: No, just strings. I'm modified the call to `cbind`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236306/pass-arguments-to-a-function-from-each-row-a-matrix-i-keep-getting-this-error/9236695#9236695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach using sapply:

```
numparamvec <- function(rownum, colnum, modeltrue, modelresult)
  {
    totnum1 = numparam(modeltrue, as.integer(colnum))
    totnum2 = numparam(modelresult, as.integer(colnum))
    return(c(rownum = rownum, colnum = colnum,
      numparam_modeltrue = totnum1, numparam_modelresult = totnum2))
  }

val <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(x)),
  function(y) do.call(numparamvec, x[y, ]))

> as.data.frame(t(val))
  rownum colnum numparam_modeltrue numparam_modelresult
1    100     10                 40                   48
2    100     20                 80                   88
```

Alternative approach using `vapply`:

```
val <- t(vapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) do.call(numparamvec, x[y, ]),
  c(rownum = 0, colnum = 0, numparam_modeltrue = 0, numparam_modelresult = 0)))

> val
     rownum colnum numparam_modeltrue numparam_modelresult
[1,]    100     10                 40                   48
[2,]    100     20                 80                   88
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I suggest merging your edit to my answer with this answer (and removing it from there), since they are so similar. I think I slightly prefer the `vapply` version, because, if I understand correctly, it does some validation on the input.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, Good Suggestion. Changes made.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to it, you could use the `data.table` package.

First, create a `data.table`, add a unique identifier column `id` and set that as the key

```
library(data.table)
xDT <- as.data.table(x)
xDT[, id := seq_len(nrow(xDT))]
setkey(xDT, "id")
```

Then, using `do.call`, you can run your `numparam` function on the appropriate columns:

```
res1 <- xDT[, list(numparam_modeltrue = do.call(numparam, unname(.SD))),
  .SDcols = c(3, 2), by = key(xDT)]
res2 <- xDT[, list(numparam_modelresult = do.call(numparam, unname(.SD))),
  .SDcols = c(4, 2), by = key(xDT)]
```

Then combine the results into a data.table

```
xDT[res1][res2][, c("modeltrue", "modelresult") := NULL, with = FALSE]
   id rownum colnum numparam_modeltrue numparam_modelresult
1:  1    100     10                 40                   48
2:  2    100     20                 80                   88
```

---

**EDIT:**

As Matthew Dowle suggests, you could reach the same results without the mrege at the end by the following:

```
xDT[,numparam_modeltrue := do.call(numparam, unname(.SD)),
  .SDcols = c(3, 2), by = key(xDT)]
xDT[,numparam_modelresult := do.call(numparam, unname(.SD)),
  .SDcols = c(4, 2), by = key(xDT)]
```

And if you want to get rid of the columns `modeltrue` and `modelresult`,

```
xDT[,c("modeltrue", "modelresult") := NULL, with = FALSE]
# NOTE that with = FALSE shouldn't be necessary with data.table 1.8.3
# But I'm still with 1.8.2
```

Comment: +1 Could the `res1<-` and `res2<-` steps each be done in one `:=` by group; e.g., `xDT[, numparam_modeltrue := do.call(numparam, unname(.SD)), 
  .SDcols = c(3, 2), by = key(xDT)]` directly to save the `res1[res2]`?

Comment: @MatthewDowle, That would be a possibility, but the two functions refer to different sets of columns, and I defined `.SDcols` to correspond appropriately. An attempt at subsetting `.SD` didn't work out yet...

Comment: I edited my comment a few times, apols. I mean two `:=`-by-group, and no `res1[res2]`.

Comment: Ah yes. Added your suggested alternative, @MatthewDowle

Comment: Cool. Nice to see you're up to speed with 1.8.3.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. One minor question. `.SDcols` specifies the cols in .SD. However, since these correspond (I think) to the `colnum` col, why are they `c(3, 2)` and `c(4, 2)`? I would have expected `c(1,2)` and `c(2,2)` instead, assuming you are using the vector is of the form c(row, col) (just a guess). If that is not it, then I don't know what notation you are using.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, You're right that `.SDcols` specifies the columns that `.SD` should contain. In your data.frame `x` (and the data.table `xDT`), the columns we want when calculating `numparam_modeltrue` are `modeltrue` and `colnum` in that order, and those are columns 3 and 2, respectively. When calculating `numparam_modelresult`, we want columns 4 and 2. Is that clearer?

Comment: In my case, the combination of `rownum` and `colnum` are in fact not unique. Using your code in this case gives an error; I'm not sure why. What method should one use to get around this?

Comment: @FaheemMitha, in that case, you could create a unique identifier, as the above edits show. Or you could put some time into further vectorizing your functions (I don't know if it's possible), which would avoid the problem of going row-by-row.

Comment: @BenBarnes: Thanks for the clarification. I did something similar in my answer. I'm still unclear why the unique identifier is necessary, though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha, The `by` argument refers to the unique identifier column(s), without which the expression operates on the entire data structure. With a unique identifier, the expression operates on one row at a time, without the need to use `as.list` and preserving the data.table structure (instead of converting to a matrix).

Answer (score 1):

The following code sort of works. It is not very pretty, though. Suggestions for improvement welcome. In particular,
it would be nice to not have to transpose the matrix and add the column names, and also, since it returns a matrix, there is still
that annoying issue where the integers are converted to strings. Thanks to [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel)
for the tip regarding [his answer to "Pass arguments to a function from each row of a matrix"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236695/350713).

```
completemodel <- function(model, colnum)
{
  modlst = c()
  tuplenum = length(model)
  if(tuplenum != 0)
    for(i in 1:tuplenum)
      modlst = c(modlst, model[[i]])
  index = seq(0, colnum-1)
  inddiff = setdiff(index, modlst)
  inddifflen = length(inddiff)
  for(i in seq(length.out=inddifflen))
    model = append(model, inddiff[i])
  return(model)
}

##   Calculate number of parameters in model.
numparam <- function(mod, colnum)
  {
    library(RJSONIO)
    mod = fromJSON(mod)
    print(paste("mod", mod))
    mod = completemodel(mod, colnum)
    totnum = 0
    for(tup in mod)
      totnum = totnum +(4**length(tup))
    return(totnum)
  }

numparamvec <- function(rownum, colnum, modeltrue, modelresult)
  {
    totnum1 = numparam(modeltrue, as.integer(colnum))
    totnum2 = numparam(modelresult, as.integer(colnum))
    return(c(rownum, colnum, totnum1, totnum2))
  }

x = cbind.data.frame(rownum=c(100, 100), colnum=c(10, 20), modeltrue=c("[]", "[]"), modelresult=c("[[1,2]]","[[1,3]]"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
val = t(apply(x, 1, function(x)do.call(numparamvec, as.list(x))))
colnames(val) = c("rownum", "colnum", "numparam_modeltrue", "numparam_modelresult")
```

Comment: @BenBarnes: The resulting data frame, however, has integers as strings. Should one just run a converter over the data frame, or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: The problem with conversion of the integers to character happens when using the `apply` function, which calls `as.matrix` on 2-D objects. If there are any non-numeric, -complex, or -logical data in the data.frame, `as.matrix` coerces your data to character. `vapply` allows you to specify the format of the output. (I'll add an example to your post.)

Comment: And the result is a `matrix`, not a `data.frame`!

Comment: @BenBarnes: Thanks for the improved version. I had trouble with the FUN.VALUE argument. It seems from the (scant) documentation that this gives the type and length of the return value from FUN. However, the rules are not precisely stated. I tried using `data.frame(rownum = 0, colnum = 0, numparam_modeltrue = 0, numparam_modelresult = 0)` but got an error message. The idea was to get a data frame returned instead of a matrix.

Comment: @BenBarnes: I suggest you split off your version into a separate answer. That way people can upvote it, and I might choose it as my preferred answer. Except for having to transpose and convert to data frame, it looks good.