# Techniques for creating vectors and parsing arguments for R's optim function from matrices, lists of parameters- clever ways to reconstruct arguments?

Tags: r, parsing, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking at what must be a common problem: I have a multivariate likelihood I wish to optimise, using `optim` in `R` with multiple inputs: two to three mean vectors as well as two to three covariance matrices as well as some other parameters. It is quite difficult to assemble them all into a long vector and reconstruct from that vector the parameters, keeping track which was which.

So far, my approach has been this:

```
make_parameter_vector = function(gamma,K_prop,Phi,K,p,params_list)
{
  l = K*p + 2*(K-1)^2 + (p+ (p^2-p)/2 ) * K + (K-1) 
  
  parameter_vector = vector(mode="numeric",length=l)
        
  
  parameter_vector[1:(K-1)] = as.vector(gamma)
  parameter_vector[((K-1)+1) : ( (K-1) + (K-1)^2)] = as.vector(K_prop)
  
  parameter_vector[(( (K-1) + (K-1)^2) + 1) : ( (K-1) + (K-1)^2  + (K-1)^2 )] = as.vector(Phi)
  
  mus = do.call(c,lapply(params_list,function(regime){regime$mu}))
  
  
  parameter_vector[( (K-1) + (K-1)^2  + (K-1)^2  + 1  ) : ((K-1) + (K-1)^2  + (K-1)^2  + K*p )   ] = mus
  
  sigmas = do.call(c,lapply(params_list,function(regime){regime$sigma[upper.tri(regime$sigma,diag = TRUE)]}))
  
  parameter_vector[((K-1) + (K-1)^2  + (K-1)^2  + K*p + 1) :((K-1) + (K-1)^2  + (K-1)^2  + K*p  + K * (p + (p^2-p)/2 )) ] = sigmas
  
  parameter_vector
}
```

which does the job, i.e. it assembles a parameter vector  from a list of mean vectors and covariances matrices plus some other parameters relevant for the problem but that is for a comparatively small problem and debugging it was extremely fiddly.

Moreover, I had to write an inverse function, that takes the `par` element of the `optim` output and restores my original objects again to be used inside the likelihood to be optimised. Now, I am changing the problem slightly, and need to write an even bigger version of the above. I am wondering if there are clever techniques I can use to make the code a little more maintainable and extendable, something that parses a bit more intelligently?

Alternatively, do some packages exist that do that? Of course, the `optim` function is written such that it can accommodate anything, so it does not care what the individual parameters mean, but from an 'API' point of view, it's quite tricky to work with it once your problem exceeds a handful of scalar parameters. I am sure this problem must come up a lot given the infinite amount of optimisation problems that all have to fit the pattern of the `optim` function.

So far, the only related question I have seen is this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235781/how-can-i-pass-multiple-arguments-to-a-function-as-a-single-vector) but it does not really answer that question.

Comment: An inverse function is not needed.  Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640006/how-can-i-minimize-this-function/66640449#66640449

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you! It looks like *only* an inverse function is needed, as `proj` sends vectors back to their more 'interpretable' format. I was hoping to learn how to construct parameter vectors a little more easily.